# Event listener getting in way of changing slider value JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, slider, listener

I am making a slider that moves as a song plays using the MediaPlayer class from JavaFX. This works completely fine and the slider moves with the song. If the slider is dragged, it changes the location of the song (using the .seek() method). The only problem occurs when I click the slider. The song does not move and I think this is because the listener looking at the position of the song is still going and this is moving the slider to its next position. I think this is blocking the user's click but am unsure how to fix it. Whether it would mean pausing the listener or something I'm not sure?

```
protected void updateValues() {
            if (playTime != null && progressBar != null && volume != null) {
               Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    Duration currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
                    duration = player.getMedia().getDuration();
                    playTime.setText(formatTime(currentTime, duration));
                    progressBar.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                    if (!progressBar.isDisabled() 
                      && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) 
                      && !progressBar.isValueChanging()) {
                        progressBar.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis()
                            * 100.0);
                    }
                  }
               });
            }
    }

progressBar.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            player.seek(duration.multiply(progressBar.getValue()/100.0));
        }
});
```

If it is helpful, I have followed this: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/playercontrol.htm

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to add [setOnMouseClicked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseClicked-javafx.event.EventHandler-) to get triggered an event on mouse-click,

```
progressBar.setOnMouseClicked(e -> 
    player.seek(duration.multiply(progressBar.getValue()/100.0))
);
```

If you want to go with mouse-event to have both cases, you may need to add two mouse event handlers `setOnMouseReleased`(for dragging-and-release your slider) and `setOnMouseClicked` (for clicking your slider). But I suggest you add a [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to your slider instead of setting mouse event listeners.

```
progressBar.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    player.seek(duration.multiply(newValue.doubleValue()/100.0))
);
```